# .htaccess redirecttion and german characters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

I'm trying to redirect some files with german letters

for example:

```
RedirectMatch München.php /de/München/
```

Everything seems to working fine, but I found that /de/München/ directory is assumed as unvisited URL. I looked into my history and I found that there are two directories:

`/de/M%C3%BCnchen/`

`/de/M%c3%bcnchen/`

As you can see there is a difference in CAPS.

Is there any way to set more accurate htaccess redirection or
is it too fatal for search engines ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try mod_rewrite based rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^München\.php$ /de/München/ [L,NE,B,R]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: This doesn't redirect, but it replaces the content. Now /Münche/München.php looks just like /München/

Comment: Thank you very much, but I decide to change the whole concept of the project!